# Displaying terms and conditions on AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to display a `UIAlertController` for terms an conditions on `appdelegate` first, if the user click "Agree", I can then procced to my viewController but if the user click "Cancel", then the app should remain on Splash screen. I have the below code but it shows my viewController without uinavigationController and with no functionality.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![userDefaults boolForKey:@"TermsAndConditions"]) {

        _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
        _window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        _window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
        _window.backgroundColor = [UIColor prosenseWhiteColor];

        UIImageView *windowImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Defaulte"]];
        [windowImage setFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
        [windowImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [_window addSubview:windowImage];

        [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"termsAndConditions" ofType:@"txt"];
        NSString *tsAndCs = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

        UIAlertController *termsAndConditionsController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Terms and conditions" message:tsAndCs preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *agree = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Agree" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

            [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

            [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"TermsAndConditions"];
            [userDefaults synchronize];

                        UIStoryboard *st_board = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                        PTPdfFileListViewController *pdfFileListView = (PTPdfFileListViewController*)[st_board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PTPdfFileListViewController"];
                        self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal;
                        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
                        [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:pdfFileListView animated:NO completion:nil];
        }];

        UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
            NSLog(@"Cancel");
        }];

        [termsAndConditionsController addAction:cancel];
        [termsAndConditionsController addAction:agree];
        [_window.rootViewController presentViewController:termsAndConditionsController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }else {
        NSLog(@"accepted terms already");
    }
}
```

what is it that Im doing wrong ?

Comment: Hope you set your "viewController" as an initial Viewcontroller. That may be the reason the blank viewcontroller is showing after splash screen. Can you pls check that? Thanks.

Comment: Why you make this too much complicated. Just create a UIveiw and disply it on rootviewcontroller once that accdept then dont load it.

Comment: @Nitin Gohel I have tried that, I thought there might be a better way to do it since the one you suggesting is showing the rootview first for 2 sec and then show the uiview for terms and conditions

Answer (score 0):

You should embedded PTPdfFileListViewController in UINavigationController as root and present that UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pushViewController` instead of `presentViewController`, then it will be in your main application's navigation controller.

The user will be able to go back, so I'm not sure it's the solution you're looking for.

Solution without the back button:

```
[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController setViewControllers:@[pdfFileListView] animated:NO];
```